# How to make stopwatch synchronized with server in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a game in which a timer will be needed, but the one made in js has a very long delay and on each device it is different, which in the case of a ranking where milliseconds count is unacceptable.
I want to create a stopwatch that will be synchronized with the server time and will have the smallest local delay and will show the elapsed time with an accuracy of 0.01 seconds. Any idea how i can do this?

My code look like this:

```
   var stopper = setInterval(myTimer, 10);
   let time = 0;
   let run = true;
   function myTimer() {
     if(run) {
       time += 0.01;
       //update time display
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep something `startTime` on the server and use on the client to calculate passed time.
If you need to keep the time and update necessarily then try to use [websocket](https://javascript.info/websocket)